# MySQL Join and COUNT(*) query

Tags: mysql, database

I have a problem. Solution down to lack of SQL knowledge on my part.
I have 2 tables.

```
Table : Jobs
+---+----------+
|ID | JobName  |
+---+----------+
| 1 | Tinker   |
| 2 | Tailor   |
| 3 | Soldier  |
| 4 | Sailor   |
+---+----------+

Table : Applied
+---+--------------+--------+
|ID | JobAppliedID | Name   |
+---+--------------+--------+
|1  | 1            |Cliff   |
|2  | 2            |John    |
|3  | 2            |Ringo   |
|4  | 2            |Paul    |
+---+--------------+--------+
```

Now, what I want to do is create an SQL that will just do a simple SELECT on table JOBS, ...

SELECT * FROM Jobs;

But I want to bring back in that SELECT a count of how many times each job has been applied for. So for example it will return the following.

```
+---+----------+-------+
|ID | JobName  | Count |
+---+----------+-------+
| 1 | Tinker   |   1   |
| 2 | Tailor   |   3   |
| 3 | Soldier  |   0   |
| 4 | Sailor   |   0   |
+---+----------+-------+
```

I think I need an embed SELECT but I just do not know where to start.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a left join like so... Use coalesce to handle null values

```
SELECT j.*, COUNT(a.jobappliedid) AS numApplied
FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN applied a ON a.jobappliedid = j.ID
GROUP BY j.id
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/194069/3/0)

Comment: `COUNT(a.jobappliedid)` would do the trick without `COALESCE`. And even more - your `COUNT(*)` will *always* return at least 1 row, never `0` or `NULL`. And even further - `COUNT(expr)` never returns `NULL`.

Comment: @zerkms yup you're right I'm on my mobile so I didn't even have a chance to test either lol

Comment: Thank you guys. I was nearly right, but didnt have GROUP BY in place.